# how to Add a formula in excel cell using Microsoft graph API?

Tags: c#, excel, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to add a content to a cell in Excel using Microsoft Graph's [Excel API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/workbook). I am able to add content using `PATCH` method but when I try to add a formula, it does not behave like a formula. If I pass something like    `'formulas': '=sum(2+2)'`, it does not behave as it should.

Result i am getting is in snip:
[image]

Is this doable?

here is my code:

```
//Set up workbook and worksheet endpoints
var workbookEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/" +
    fileId + "/workbook";

var worksheetsEndpoint = workbookEndpoint + "/worksheets";

var patchMethod = new HttpMethod("PATCH");

var summaryTableRowJson = "{" +
    "'formulas': '=sum(2+2)'" +
    "}";

var colNamePatchBody = new StringContent(summaryTableRowJson);
colNamePatchBody.Headers.Clear();
colNamePatchBody.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

var colNameRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(patchMethod, worksheetsEndpoint +
    "('" + worksheetName + "')/range(address='Sheet1!B2')")
{
    Content = colNamePatchBody
};

var colNameResponseMessage = await client.SendAsync(colNameRequestMessage);
```

Comment: Could you make sure your screenshot reflects the code you ran? I'm a little concerned that you're screenshot shows `B2` but your code is setting `C12`. Before I go down a rabbit hole chasing why it's getting the cell wrong, I just want to make sure your code and screenshort are both acurate.

Comment: I updated my question and snip.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass this in via the [`formulas`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/range#json-representation) rather than the `values` property:

```
{
  "formulas" : "=sum(2+2)"
}
```

You should also consider using the [Microsoft Graph Client Library for .NET](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) instead of rolling your own raw HTTP calls. It will save you a ton of headaches over time. It also results in much cleaner code:

```
await graphClient.Me
    .Drive
    .Items["id"]
    .Workbook
    .Worksheets["Sheet1"]
    .Range("C12")
    .Request()
    .PatchAsync(new WorkbookRange()
    {
        Formulas = JArray.Parse(@"[['=2.2']]")
    });
```

Comment: I replace values to formulas. result is still same. with existing code. otherwise i would try shared Graph Client Library.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the actual result you're seeing? I understand it isn't "behaving like a formula" but that doesn't really explain how it _is_ behaving or what you're seeing.

Comment: I have added a result snip in question. i would like to ask one more thing, does graph client library support with sahrepoint and sharepoint subsites as well?

Comment: The SDK supports everything in Microsoft Graph v1.0 (with the exception of a couple of really edge cases). It also supports calling the HTTP client directly (which gets you around the 1-2 edge cases).

Comment: I simply tried Microsoft Graph Client Library for .NET. but i am getting same result as my custom code. you did pass '=2.2' as formula value. isn't should be '=2+2'? I tired with '=2.2' and '=2+2'. same result as before.